# How to implement interface in angular form build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interface

I was trying to implement interface in angular formbuilder(reactive form) but when I created interface with all validators and kind of this am getting error

**only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.**

```
export Interface user {
firstName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(50),
          ValidationService.alphanumericValidator,
        ],
      ],
      lastName: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(50),
          ValidationService.alphanumericValidator,
        ],
}
```

Comment: must be a variable or const, not an interface

Comment: share your thoughts about why you want to declare that interface